# facing this runtime error when trying to write a code to firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

```
import 'package:chatapp/app/routes/app_pages.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:get_storage/get_storage.dart';
import 'package:google_sign_in/google_sign_in.dart';

class AuthController extends GetxController {
  var isSkipIntro = false.obs;
  var isAuth = false.obs;

  GoogleSignIn _googleSignIn = GoogleSignIn();
  GoogleSignInAccount? _currentUser;
  UserCredential? userCredential;

  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  Future<void> firstInitialized() async {
    await autoLogin().then((value) {
      isAuth.value = true;
    });

    await skipIntro().then((value) {
      isSkipIntro.value = true;
    });
  }

  Future<bool> skipIntro() async {
    final box = GetStorage();
    if (box.read("skipIntro") != null || box.read("skipIntro") == true) {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<bool> autoLogin() async {
    try {
      final isSignIn = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();
      if (isSignIn) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> login() async {
    try {
      await _googleSignIn.signOut();

      await _googleSignIn.signIn().then((value) => _currentUser = value);

      final isSignin = await _googleSignIn.isSignedIn();

      if (isSignin) {
        print(_currentUser);

        final gooogleAuth = await _currentUser!.authentication;

        final credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
          idToken: gooogleAuth.idToken,
          accessToken: gooogleAuth.accessToken,
        );

        await FirebaseAuth.instance
            .signInWithCredential(credential)
            .then((value) => userCredential = value);

        print("USER CREDENTIAL");
        print(userCredential);

        final box = GetStorage();
        if (box.read("skipIntro") != null) {
          box.remove("skipIntro");
        }
        box.write("skipIntro", true);

        CollectionReference users = firestore.collection("users");
        users.doc(_currentUser!.email).set({
          "UID": userCredential!.user!.uid,
          "name": _currentUser!.displayName,
          "email": _currentUser!.email,
          "photoURL": _currentUser!.photoUrl,
          "status": "",
          "createAt":
              userCredential!.user!.metadata.creationTime!.toIso8601String(),
          "lastSignInTime":
              userCredential!.user!.metadata.lastSignInTime!.toIso8601String(),
          "updateTime": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
        });

        isAuth.value = true;
        Get.offAllNamed(Routes.HOME);
      } else {
        print("TIDAK BERHASIL LOGIN");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }

  Future<void> logOut() async {`your text`
    await _googleSignIn.signOut();
    Get.offAllNamed(Routes.LOGIN);
  }
}
```

This is the authcontroller. The problem is when I'm trying to save the usercredential to the firestore after sign-in, this runtime error appears on my console, but i did login, the account appears on my firebase authentication but data(usercredential) cant be written in the firestore with the error i say before.

I'm expecting the the usercredential can be written in the firestore with the document id by _currentuser email. i have set the firestore rules to true but the same error still happens

Comment: What is the error you're getting? I'm not seeing it in the post.